# js update nested objects with only specified properties

Tags: javascript, object

I would like to update an object, with a series of nested objects held within. I want to be able to do this by passing an 'updating' object which contains some keys present in the original object but may omit some others. Any keys present within the updating object should overwrite the original object's relevant keys. However, any keys which were omitted in the updating object should remain within the original object.

Considering an example object like so:

```js
let obj = {
  a:{
    b:{
      c:1,
      d:2,
    },
    e:{
      f:3
    }
  }
}
```

Using some method, apply the following object to the `obj`

```js
{
  a:{
    b:{
      c:"boo"
    }
  }
}
```

this update should update `obj.a.b.c` while maintaining `obj.a.b.d` and `obj.a.e`

I have tried using the `Object.assign(obj,{ a:{ b:{ c:"boo" } } })` method. However, doing so returns the following - which is not what I need.

```js
{
  a:{
    b:{
      c:"boo"
    }
  }
}
```

As shown, `obj.a.e` and `obj.a.b.c` are no longer present, although they were not specified in the updating object - I would like these keys to remain.

Comment: Can't you do ```obj.a.b.c = "boo"``` ? If update you want is overwriting the value?

Comment: @Newbee the object shown in the question is just an example i put together. In reality, the object will be dynamic and i cannot be certain of the structure of the object. I would also like the capability to update multiple keys at different depths.

Answer (score 0):

We can write a recursive function that walks down the nested object and update:

Assumption: The structure of object never changes when updating. For example instead of "boo" you cannot specify object like `{ z: 1 }` as an update value

```js
const isObject = (value) => value !== null && typeof value == "object";

const update = (obj, updateObj) => {
    // if either obj or updateObj is undefined, no point in going down further 
    if (obj && updateObj) {
        // walk down the updateObj and update for the same keys
        const keys = Object.keys(updateObj);
        const targetKeys = Object.keys(obj);
        for (const key of keys) {
            // if value is an object walk down, otherwise update the value
            if (isObject(updateObj[key])) {
                update(obj[key], updateObj[key]);
            } else if (targetKeys.indexOf(key) !== -1) {
                obj[key] = updateObj[key];
            }
        }
    }
};

update(obj, updateObj);
```